# How do I split a text file containing multiple iCalendar events?

Tags: ruby, file, split, icalendar

I have a text file from a Google calendar. Each event on the calendar has 14 different fields but all the events are stacked on top of each other like so:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160304T093000Z
DTEND:20160304T143000Z
DTSTAMP:20160417T141329Z
UID:
CREATED:20160228T142659Z
DESCRIPTION:For assembler
LAST-MODIFIED:20160304T133208Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Richmond
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160312
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160313
DTSTAMP:20160417T1413
........etc, etc.
```

I want to split the text file into events each with there 14 fields and save it as an array. I have been trying to open the file and read by line, but it is the splitting into the fields that is troubling me.

Comment: Try using the `split` method of the String class, which is documented here: http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split  If you continue to have trouble, you should really post your code and explain what is wrong with it.  Without seeing your code, it's hard to guess what your problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you use `File.read(fname)` to "gulp" the file into the variable `str`, where:

```
str =<<_
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160304T093000Z
DTEND:20160304T143000Z
DTSTAMP:20160417T141329Z
CREATED:20160228T142659Z
DESCRIPTION:For assembler
LAST-MODIFIED:20160304T133208Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160314T093000Z
DTEND:20160314T143000Z
DTSTAMP:20160427T141329Z
CREATED:20160228T142659Z
DESCRIPTION:For assembler
LAST-MODIFIED:20160314T133208Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
_
```

If the file is large, you might instead read it line-by-line, using, say, [IO::foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach).

You can now break the string up as follows.

```
arr = str.split(/\n{2,}/).map { |s| s.split(/\n/) }
  #=> [["BEGIN:VEVENT", "DTSTART:20160304T093000Z", "DTEND:20160304T143000Z",
  #     "DTSTAMP:20160417T141329Z", "CREATED:20160228T142659Z",
  #     "DESCRIPTION:For assembler", "LAST-MODIFIED:20160304T133208Z",
  #     "SEQUENCE:0", "STATUS:CONFIRMED", "END:VEVENT"
  #    ],
  #    ["BEGIN:VEVENT", "DTSTART:20160314T093000Z", "DTEND:20160314T143000Z", 
  #      "DTSTAMP:20160427T141329Z", "CREATED:20160228T142659Z",
  #      "DESCRIPTION:For assembler", "LAST-MODIFIED:20160314T133208Z",
  #      "SEQUENCE:0", "STATUS:CONFIRMED", "END:VEVENT"
  #    ]
  #   ]
```

If you don't want the lines beginning `BEGIN:` or `END:`, change `s.split(/\n/)` to:

```
s.split(/\n/).reject { |t| t.start_with?("BEGIN:", "END:") } }
```

Next, I expect you will want to convert this array into a more useful data structure, such as an array of hashes. You could do that as follows (recognizing that some modifications may be required to suit your requirements).

```
 arr.map do |a|
   a.each_with_object({}) do |b,h|
     key, value = b.split(':')
     begin
       dt = DateTime.iso8601(value)
     rescue ArgumentError
       nil
     end
     h[key.to_sym] = dt ? dt : value
   end
 end
   #=> [{:BEGIN=>"VEVENT",
   #     :DTSTART=>#<DateTime: 2016-03-04T09:30:00+00:00 (...)>,
   #     :DTEND=>#<DateTime: 2016-03-04T14:30:00+00:00 (...)>,
   #     :DTSTAMP=>#<DateTime: 2016-04-17T14:13:29+00:00 (...)>,
   #     :CREATED=>#<DateTime: 2016-02-28T14:26:59+00:00 (...)>,
   #     :DESCRIPTION=>"For assembler",
   #     :"LAST-MODIFIED"=>#<DateTime: 2016-03-04T13:32:08+00:00 (...)>,
   #     :SEQUENCE=>"0",
   #     :STATUS=>"CONFIRMED",
   #     :END=>"VEVENT"
   #    },
   #    {:BEGIN=>"VEVENT",
   #     :DTSTART=>#<DateTime: 2016-03-14T09:30:00+00:00 (...)>,
   #     :DTEND=>#<DateTime: 2016-03-14T14:30:00+00:00 (...)>,
   #     :DTSTAMP=>#<DateTime: 2016-04-27T14:13:29+00:00 (...)>,
   #     :CREATED=>#<DateTime: 2016-02-28T14:26:59+00:00 (...)>,
   #     :DESCRIPTION=>"For assembler",
   #     :"LAST-MODIFIED"=>#<DateTime: 2016-03-14T13:32:08+00:00 (...)>,
   #     :SEQUENCE=>"0",
   #     :STATUS=>"CONFIRMED",
   #     :END=>"VEVENT"
   #    }
   #   ]
```

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

You should really use an [iCalendar parser](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/calendars) for this, but either your data is malformed or the [icalendar 2.3.0](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar) parser is currently broken. However, you can parse well-formed iCal event data with a regular expression, and then modify your data structure to suit your use case.

### Parse iCal Data with Regular Expressions

While a full-fledged parser is better, as a quick-and-dirty alternative you can scan for events in a file and then split them into an array of arrays:

```
ics = File.read '/tmp/foo.ics'
events = ics.scan(/^BEGIN:VEVENT.*?END:VEVENT/m).map { |e| e.split ?\n }
```

In this example, `events.first` will yield elements like `"BEGIN:VEVENT"` and `"DTSTART:20160304T093000Z"`. This is what you asked for in your question, but is probably not what you really need. You will likely need to put the event data into a more flexible data structure (e.g. a [Hash](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) or [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html)) if you aren't working directly with iCalendar event objects.

### Converting Event Arrays to Hashes

Once you have an array of events, you can then use [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-split) or [String#partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-partition) to convert the individual events into a hash or other key/value data structure. For example, using the same *events* variable from the previous section:

```
event_hash = Hash[*events.first.flat_map { |e| e.split ?: }]
```

Using awesome_print on *event_hash* displays the following nicely-formatted content from our variable:

```
{
               "BEGIN" => "VEVENT",
             "DTSTART" => "20160304T093000Z",
               "DTEND" => "20160304T143000Z",
             "DTSTAMP" => "20160417T141329Z",
                 "UID" => "CREATED",
    "20160228T142659Z" => "DESCRIPTION",
       "For assembler" => "LAST-MODIFIED",
    "20160304T133208Z" => "LOCATION",
            "SEQUENCE" => "0",
              "STATUS" => "CONFIRMED",
             "SUMMARY" => "Richmond",
              "TRANSP" => "OPAQUE",
                 "END" => "VEVENT"
}
```

This hash can then be manipulated any way you like, or used to create a more suitable object such as Icalendar::Event. The original post had no description of the actual output desired, so beyond this point your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Cary's answer is nice, but I just want to note that you should be able to load the data using the **[`vformat` gem](https://github.com/martinpovolny/vformat-ruby)**, too. The gem provides nice methods to access the event properties.

Unfortunately it seems that this gem cannot be simply installed by `gem install 'vformat'`, it has to be installed directly from github (which is easy using bundler). The following is an example of reading two events:

Installing the gem:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'vformat', git: "https://github.com/martinpovolny/vformat-ruby.git"

$ bundle
...
```

Reading two events:

```
str =<<_
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160304T093000Z
DTEND:20160304T143000Z
DTSTAMP:20160417T141329Z
CREATED:20160228T142659Z
DESCRIPTION:For assembler
LAST-MODIFIED:20160304T133208Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160314T093000Z
DTEND:20160314T143000Z
DTSTAMP:20160427T141329Z
CREATED:20160228T142659Z
DESCRIPTION:For assembler
LAST-MODIFIED:20160314T133208Z
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
_

require 'vformat/icalendar'

events = VFormat.decode(str)
events.count
# => 2

events.first.DESCRIPTION.value
# => "For assembler"

events.second.STATUS.value
# => "CONFIRMED"
```